# Map editor which can export to simple .txt file

Tags: text, dictionary, export, tiles

I'm developing simple game that load map form txt which format something like this:

```
# Map file for tile-based game
# (Lines that start with '#' are comments)
# The tiles are:
#   (Space) Empty tile
#   A..Z    Tiles A through Z
#   s       Star
#   1       Bad Guy 1
#   2       Bad Guy 2









   2  IAJ  ssssss     1     1     
IABABAELFBABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABJ
LMLMLMCKDLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLM
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
```

Where i can find simple map editor like this? Simple map editor

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to find an existing editor that writes to your specific file format, but tile map editors like [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) write to a simple file format that is easy for you to parse. Another tile map editor is [Mappy.](http://tilemap.co.uk/mappy.php)

Comment: Yes, i found "Tiled"(map editors). And it pretty simple xml structure(tmx). I have write code to parse .tmx.